Android : fragment navigation with parentFragmentManager
I have created from Android studio a new Android ( Kotlin) project based on the « Bottom Navigation View Activity » template.

So, 1 activity with its XML template that contains the navigation part and 1 fragment only :
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingTop="?attr/actionBarSize">

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment_activity_main"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/nav_view"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/mobile_navigation" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

and my MainActivity.kl file :
 override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        val navView: BottomNavigationView = binding.navView

        val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment_activity_main)
        // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
        // menu should be considered as top level destinations.
        val appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(
            setOf(
                R.id.navigation_home, R.id.navigation_dashboard, R.id.navigation_notifications
            )
        )
        setupActionBarWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)
        navView.setupWithNavController(navController)
}

When the first fragment ( "1" on the screenshot) is displayed, I want to add a button to navigate to another fragment, and allow the user , when clicking on the "back" button of the device, to come back to the original fragment. I tried with the fragmentManager approach as described in the official documentation without any results:
Row(
        verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,
        modifier = Modifier
            .padding(10.dp)
            .border(1.dp, Color.DarkGray, RoundedCornerShape(5.dp))
            .background(Color.LightGray)
            .padding(10.dp)
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .clickable {

                fragment.parentFragmentManager.commit {
                    replace<ComboListFragment>(R.id.nav_host_fragment_activity_main)
                    setReorderingAllowed(true)
                    addToBackStack("name") // Name can be null
                }
...

It ends with the error below:

Process: com.example.xxxxxx, PID: 4906
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The fragment
ComboListFragment{3cdca04} (5b0fcda6-a500-449f-a227-3fa1a9c8b2af
id=0x7f0901a8) is unknown to the FragmentNavigator. Please use the
navigate() function to add fragments to the FragmentNavigator managed
FragmentManager.


You are using NavHostFragment and the Navigation Component, so you should never, ever be doing FragmentTransactions yourself, but calling navController.navigate to add a new screen to your back stack. Have you following one of the codelabs around using Navigation to learn what APIs you should be using?

Thank you for your comment. I have read the whole documentation, but it is still not clear. I want to replace it with a fragment using compose ( without XML) . Canot find similar use-case in the doc
